# OnBase: Transfer content from one database to another

Tags: migration, transfer, onbase

We want to move our OnBase content from one environment to another.

I know we can move the files themselved by attaching the storage drive from one virtual server to the new host.

But I'm hoping to find out how to move the index information from the source database to the destination database.

Are there any totorials or documentation that I can refer to?

Thank you,
-tomas